# Jquery doing else action on ajax response regardless of response

Tags: jquery, ajax, debugging, if-statement

Hi this was working last night when I finished my 12 hour shift of embarrassing web developing and this morning regardless of if the response if 'success' or not it still does the else action. Can anyone see anything wrong with this because I can't :(

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
$(document).ready(function(){

    $("#submit").click(function(){
        if ($('#name').val().length != 0 && $('#email').val().length != 0 && $('#message').val().length != 0 && $('#code').val().length != 0){  
            var action = $("#contact_form").attr('action');
            var form_data = {
                name:$("#name").val(),
                email:$("#email").val(),
                message:$("#message").val(),
                code:$("#code").val(),
                is_ajax:1
            };
            $.ajax({
                type:"POST",
                url:action,
                data:form_data,
                success: function(response) {
                    if(response == 'success')
                        $("#contact_form").slideUp('slow', function() {
                            $("#contact_message").html("<p class='success'>Thanks for your message, please close this window.</p>");
                        });
                    else
                        $("#contact_message").html("<p class='error'>Security code not correct.</p>");
                }
            });
            return false;
        };
    });

    // refresh captcha
    $("#refresh").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
        change_captcha();
    });

    function change_captcha(){
        document.getElementById('captcha').src="./static/classes/get_captcha.php?rnd="+Math.random();
    };
});
</script>
```

If anyone wishes to see the page I am using it on its, http://pug4u.com/contact.php

Comment: Add `console.log(response)` before your condition in the success handler and double check what response you are receiving back from the request.

Comment: I am using firebug the response is correct, I also added it to the else message output so I could see it visually, regardless of response it is doing the else :/

Comment: Try doing `if ($.trim(response) == 'success')` to make sure whitespace isn't messing it up.

Comment: @Anthony Grist thanks I should of known... I was testing this last night without the mailer side of things added and added that this morning this was obviously adding something to the response.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding curly braces around your if and else

```
if (respone == "success") { }
```

It might be a semicolon inserted that messes up things for you.

Comment: Well I thought that would be it because yeah thats something I should of not only done but noticed, but no it didn't have any effect, Thanks for pointing that out I am so tired I didn't notice.

Comment: Although it's always good advice to use the curly braces, there's no ASI issue with that part of the code.

Comment: Yeah, it was more of a pointer. I think your problem is with the response. Have you tried breaking in the susccess method and running response == 'success' int the console?